# Using Variables in Filepaths in Batch Files

Tags: variables, batch-file, directory, set, xcopy

I'm trying to create a small script that will allow me to copy folders and it's contents from a certain directory on my computer to another one. So far, here's what I have:

```
@echo off
SET /P %TARGET%=Enter variable name:
xcopy "C:\Folder1\%TARGET%" "C:\Folder2"
pause
```

It returns with `INVALID PATH, 0 FILE(S) COPIED.`

how would I need to alter the script to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `%` when you declare the variable :

```
@echo off

SET /P TARGET=Enter variable name:

xcopy "C:\Folder1\%TARGET%\*.*" "C:\Folder2"

pause
```